# VBA extract worksheets from different excel data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a a big problem with my VBA macro and I cant find a solution, so I hope you guys can do.

I would like to extract worksheets from different excel data, copy them, and paste the extracted worksheets into my main excel.

In the latest version excel is pasting all one after the other but it should pasting the whole worksheet into a new one.

This is the code...

```
Public Sub Daten_mehrerer_Dateien_zusammenfuehren()

On Error GoTo errExit
Dim WBQ As Workbook
Dim WBZ As Workbook
Dim varDateien As Variant
Dim lngAnzahl As Long
Dim lngLastQ As Long

Set WBZ = ActiveWorkbook
'Altdaten auf Zielblatt löschen
WBZ.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:IV65536").ClearContents

varDateien = _
Application.GetOpenFilename("Datei (*.xlsx),*.xls", False, "Bitte gewünschte Datei(en) markieren", False, True)

With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  .EnableEvents = False
  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For lngAnzahl = LBound(varDateien) To UBound(varDateien)
Set WBQ = Workbooks.Open(filename:=varDateien(lngAnzahl))
  lngLastQ = WBQ.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  WBQ.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:Z" & lngLastQ).Copy _
  Destination:=WBZ.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & WBZ.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
WBQ.Close
Next

With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  .EnableEvents = True
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

MsgBox "Es wurden " & UBound(varDateien) & " Dateien zusammengefügt.", 64

Exit Sub

errExit:
With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  .EnableEvents = True
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

If Err.Number = 13 Then
MsgBox "Es wurde keine Datei ausgewählt"
  Else
MsgBox "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!" & vbCr _
& "Fehlernummer: " & Err.Number & vbCr _
& "Fehlerbeschreibung: " & Err.Description
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to add a new sheet? Then `WBQ.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:Z" & lngLastQ).Copy _
  Destination:=WBZ.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & WBZ.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)` is not what you want, as it is copying the range over into an existing sheet (`WBZ.Worksheets(1)`)

Comment: Should I use a For loop for this?

Comment: To me it sounds like you want `Worksheets.Add`.